# laravel 5.4 herokuapp throws an error when uploading image to google drive

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, google-drive-api

Uploading Images using google drive api and it works fine locally but throws an error on heroku
`ErrorException in GoogleDriveAdapter.php line 1143:
 A non well formed numeric value encountered`

```
public function store() {
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
        'img' => 'required|image'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json('err');
    } else {
        $path = request()->file('img')->store('');
        $url = Storage::url($path);
        auth()->user()->addImage($url);
        return response()->json($url);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1032886/php/langage/syntaxe/non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered/). It stated that maybe one of your variables does not contain a number. You may also check the [PHP FAQs](http://php.developpez.com/faq/) and [PHP courses and tutorials](https://php.developpez.com/cours/).

Comment: i did test this code on file.txt and it works but when i try to upload an image it throws that error also the problem is only on heroku so the code tottaly works fine locally